# How do I override the Validator's approval and move the release to a next stage in Microsoft Release Management?

Tags: ms-release-management

I have set up two stages in Microsoft Release Management - QA and PROD. I setup the account ValidatorAcc to be a Validator of the QA stage.

When this person receives an email to validate the stage and for example is unable to access his/her email service for some reason, is there a way for me to override his/her approval and do it myself as an admin?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in Release Management Client if you are an admin in Release Management Server:

1. Open Release Management Client
2. Go to Releases tab
3. Click on My Approval Requests link
   [image]
4. If you do not see the release you are interested in, click on the Advanced Filter dropdown and uncheck **Show Only Mine** checkbox.
   [image]
5. Now, you will see all the releases in progress, click on the one you need and click Approve button.